# Apache/PHP access to a different sites files

Tags: shared-folders

I have two websites running Opencart on the same server, selling overlapping products.

Site 1 already has all the product images uploaded to /var/www/vhosts/site1/httpdocs/image/catalog/products but site 2 does not.

What I would like to do is allow PHP on site2 to access the /var/www/vhosts/site1/httpdocs/image/catalog/products folder as if it were within its own space ie /var/www/vhosts/site2/httpdocs/image/catalog/products

This would allow site2s PHP image processing and cacheing mechanisms to work correctly, rather than using something like an Apache Alias and also to reduce the duplication of the images across two different folders and taking up disk space.

I tried setting up a symbolic link "ln -s /var/www/vhosts/site1/httpdocs/image/catalog/products products" from within the catalog folder on site2 and whilst this has created a symbolic link, the permissions may be incorrect.

I ran a chown -h command on the symbolic link in site2 thinking that this would allow access but unfortunately not.

Is this a permissions think that can be overcome or should I be looking at this in a different way?

Comment: Is there anything that doesn't work? If so, please describe the symptoms.

Comment: The symptoms are that php/apache running under the user for site2 is not able to access the products folder from site1 if I were to use either:

https://www.site2.com/image/catalog/products/someimage.jpg

or try to access the path /var/www/vhosts/site2/httpdocs/image/catalog/products/someimage.jpg using a php script running through apache on site2

Comment: You mention something about permissions. I suppose the permissions of someimage.jpg are so that user2 can't access them. What prevents you to set up the permissions so that both users can read them? For example, put both users in the same group and make everything group-readable.

Comment: The users assigned to the site files are essentially as follows: user1:psacln & user2:psacln where user1 has read/write access to site1 files and user2 has read/write access to site2 files. Both are in the psacln group? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: This means that the files belong to group `psacln`. Not hat the two users belong to it, but the command `id user1; id user2` clarifies that. In case the users are indeed members of `psacln`, you could give group read, and if required write, access to the relevant files.

Comment: You have a "shared resource"/concurrency problem, including all the side problems that come along with it (what happens when both sites try to write data to the same shared resource? Etc.) Making a symlink a giving file permissions will not help. You will need to make 3 directory sub-trees: one for site1-only files, one for site2-only files, and one for shared files. then configure Apache/PHP to their own site1/site2 trees, and in _**both**_, add another entry for the shared tree. You will still need to handle the concurrency issues. (Apache docs have examples of all this... RTFM)

Comment: This makes sense. However could I not give READ ONLY access to the site1 files from site2 rather than READ/WRITE. I could also then ensure that SITE1 was solely responsible for WRITES?